# open saml 3 is open source and under which licence

Tags: saml, opensaml

I tried searching but could not find it. I went through documentation and github.

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Home

Comment: I think you should ask the author / copyright holder.

Comment: I'm unable to find author contact details. Can you please help me ?

Comment: You should look through the links in the wiki your referenced. It has links to the source code. Each of these files has a header with the license, plus author information. Try there.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSAML v2 is licensed under Apache License 2.0 (https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoLicense). The OpenSAML v3 wiki still is pretty thin so I couldn't find anything about licensing, but if you'll look in any source file of OpenSAML v3 you'll see that it is also under Apache 2.0.

The same goes for Shibboleth.